# Collect real time GC metrics - Golang

Tags: go, garbage-collection, metrics

Is there a straightforward way in Go to get information about the GC and heap sizes in order to expose them to a monitoring dashboard. I had a look at the runtime package but there doesnt seem to be anything that does that there. Ideally this shouldnt require any overhead like running the application in profiling mode, etc, but should be production ready.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `GODEBUG=gctrace=1` to get continuous output, which is documented in the [runtime package](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime).

Otherwise, you need to collect information from [`runtime.MemStats`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#MemStats) and [`debug.GCStats`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#GCStats).